# Python csv writer writing all contents to one cell

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write values to a csv file in python, the csv file is successfully written to but everything is written to the first cell, so nothing ends up being separated. For example,
the first cell of the csv when I open it up in excel will look like this

```
 _______ 
|100 200|
|_______|
```

when it should be

```
 _______ _______
|100    |  200  |
|_______|_______|
```

Here is my code for writing to the csv  files.

```
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,  delimiter='',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        spamwriter.writerow([min(size),min(size)])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is delimiter set to `''`? Could that be it? I'd try `','` instead.

Comment: change `delimiter=''` to `delimiter=','`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a non-blank delimiter. Your code shows the delimiter is `''`, you probably want `','`

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,  delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow([min(size),min(size)])
```

While this is right for American Windows versions, for European Windows this character is reserved as decimal simbol and the separator is set by default to the semicolon in Excel:

```
spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,  delimiter=';',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I overlooked something that simple.

Comment: LOL. Happens to the best of us;-)